How can I get a diagnostic for unreached code?
(TLA+ newbie here) I am trying to PlusCal model the double-switch lamp state machine that you can see here: https://learntla.com/topics/state-machines.html. The model works but then I knocked off one of the state transitions on purpose, to simulate a faulty model. It still passes :) How can I elicit a diagnostic about that dysfunction? Thanks!
The line is marked <== dead in the code below:
Model for the double switch: https://learntla.com/topics/state-machines.html

---- MODULE switch ----------------------------------------------------

EXTENDS TLC, Integers, Sequences

(**********************************************************************

--algorithm lamp {

fair+ process (Switch \in {1})
variables
    state \in {"BothOff", "WallOff", "LampOff", "On"};
    initialState = "BothOff";
    v1 = 2;
{
  ProcBody:
    state := "BothOff";

  EntryBothOff:
    skip;
  BodyBothOff:
    either {
        await (/\ state = initialState /\ v1 = 3); \* <== dead as v1 = 2!!
        state := "WallOff";
        goto BodyWallOff;
    } or {
        await (/\ state = initialState);
        state := "LampOff";
        goto BodyLampOff;
    };

  BodyLampOff:
    either {
        await state = "LampOff";
        state := "BothOff";
        goto BodyBothOff;
    } or {
        await state = "LampOff";
        state := "On";
        goto BodyOn;
    };

  BodyWallOff:
    either {
        await state = "WallOff";
        state := "BothOff";
        goto BodyBothOff;
    } or {
        await state = "WallOff";
        state := "On";
        goto BodyOn;
    };

  BodyOn:
    either {
        await state = "On";
        state := "LampOff";
        goto BodyLampOff;
    } or {
        await state = "On";
        state := "WallOff";
        goto BodyWallOff;
    };

} \* Switch

} \* algorithm lamp

**********************************************************************)

\* BEGIN TRANSLATION (chksum(pcal) = "e4214bef" /\ chksum(tla) = "67c8ad81")
VARIABLES pc, state, initialState, v1

vars == << pc, state, initialState, v1 >>

ProcSet == ({1})

Init == (* Process Switch *)
        /\ state \in [{1} -> {"BothOff", "WallOff", "LampOff", "On"}]
        /\ initialState = [self \in {1} |-> "BothOff"]
        /\ v1 = [self \in {1} |-> 2]
        /\ pc = [self \in ProcSet |-> "ProcBody"]

ProcBody(self) == /\ pc[self] = "ProcBody"
                  /\ state' = [state EXCEPT ![self] = "BothOff"]
                  /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![self] = "EntryBothOff"]
                  /\ UNCHANGED << initialState, v1 >>

EntryBothOff(self) == /\ pc[self] = "EntryBothOff"
                      /\ TRUE
                      /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![self] = "BodyBothOff"]
                      /\ UNCHANGED << state, initialState, v1 >>

BodyBothOff(self) == /\ pc[self] = "BodyBothOff"
                     /\ \/ /\ (/\ state[self] = initialState[self] /\ v1[self] = 3)
                           /\ state' = [state EXCEPT ![self] = "WallOff"]
                           /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![self] = "BodyWallOff"]
                        \/ /\ (/\ state[self] = initialState[self])
                           /\ state' = [state EXCEPT ![self] = "LampOff"]
                           /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![self] = "BodyLampOff"]
                     /\ UNCHANGED << initialState, v1 >>

BodyLampOff(self) == /\ pc[self] = "BodyLampOff"
                     /\ \/ /\ state[self] = "LampOff"
                           /\ state' = [state EXCEPT ![self] = "BothOff"]
                           /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![self] = "BodyBothOff"]
                        \/ /\ state[self] = "LampOff"
                           /\ state' = [state EXCEPT ![self] = "On"]
                           /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![self] = "BodyOn"]
                     /\ UNCHANGED << initialState, v1 >>

BodyWallOff(self) == /\ pc[self] = "BodyWallOff"
                     /\ \/ /\ state[self] = "WallOff"
                           /\ state' = [state EXCEPT ![self] = "BothOff"]
                           /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![self] = "BodyBothOff"]
                        \/ /\ state[self] = "WallOff"
                           /\ state' = [state EXCEPT ![self] = "On"]
                           /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![self] = "BodyOn"]
                     /\ UNCHANGED << initialState, v1 >>

BodyOn(self) == /\ pc[self] = "BodyOn"
                /\ \/ /\ state[self] = "On"
                      /\ state' = [state EXCEPT ![self] = "LampOff"]
                      /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![self] = "BodyLampOff"]
                   \/ /\ state[self] = "On"
                      /\ state' = [state EXCEPT ![self] = "WallOff"]
                      /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![self] = "BodyWallOff"]
                /\ UNCHANGED << initialState, v1 >>

Switch(self) == ProcBody(self) \/ EntryBothOff(self) \/ BodyBothOff(self)
                   \/ BodyLampOff(self) \/ BodyWallOff(self)
                   \/ BodyOn(self)

(* Allow infinite stuttering to prevent deadlock on termination. *)
Terminating == /\ \A self \in ProcSet: pc[self] = "Done"
               /\ UNCHANGED vars

Next == (\E self \in {1}: Switch(self))
           \/ Terminating

Spec == /\ Init /\ [][Next]_vars
        /\ \A self \in {1} : SF_vars(Switch(self))

Termination == <>(\A self \in ProcSet: pc[self] = "Done")

\* END TRANSLATION

====


Your spec does not parse after translation. What is initialState?

Apologies for the code. I have updated it. Thank you for taking a look at! initialState is "BothOff" - it can be replaced with that constant

can you also include your config file? Also, are you using the toolbox or the vscode plugin?

I am using the toolbox with an out-of-box new model: Temporal Formula: Spec, check for Deadlocks, Termination unchecked. It would look like (trying to format it but not successful):
    \* SPECIFICATION definition     SPECIFICATION     Spec     \* Generated on Tue Jul 09 10:26:28 EDT 2024

There is no dysfunction, because you have not specified any properties that would fail to be satisfied when injecting this fault. If you run your faulty version, TLC will find 9 distinct states with 16 state transitions. If you remove the fault, TLC will find 9 distinct states with 17 state transitions - it has one more state transition available to it, but it still reaches the same set of states.
If you want to inject faults that would expose a failure, you would likely have to disable more state transitions then use liveness properties; you can ask TLC to check whether your system will eventually reach some state that is now unreachable because of the transitions you disabled, and TLC will report that it cannot.

Thank you. I ended up by keeping track of transitions and adding a check like AllTransitionsVisited == <>(\A t \in DOMAIN visitedTransitions : visitedTransitions[t] = TRUE)
It is mostly automated (I am using an uml-to-pluscal translator): https://github.com/melintea/upml/blob/main/plantuml/sip/sip.tla
Reading through the doc, I am wondering if I could do the same by labeling the transitions and fiddling fairness on the labels
